# CoreAudio Input Render callback renders all 0's from external audio interface Mac OS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: c, macos, core-audio

I was working on a CoreAudio project when my Mac was on 10.11 where I took the CAPlayThroughExample (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004443-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and modified only bits and pieces of the Input and Output render functions to access different buffer streams. This code was working for Mac OS 10.11, 10.12, and 10.13. For 10.14 when playing sound from my external audio interface, there was complete silence. When I logged some of the samples from the Input Proc, the buffers were all `0.0`'s. So I downgraded my mac back down to 10.13 and the same code worked. I looked around and googled everything but can't seem to find any official resources on apple's website to see if there were any API changes.

Answer (score 2):

On 10.14 you need to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to `Info.plist` file. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos).

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. the article you sent me is great. I added the microphone permission but still i get the same thing. It's interesting that article mentions that if you get this error message `Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)` that there is something wrong with the issue. i'll have to investigate this further

Comment: So the example in the link says to add it to the plist and also add the code for verification. I followed the example and the steps to request for authorization, but now the audiobuffer list is null in the input rendercall back